# List localStorage data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, local-storage, shopping-cart

I have a question to save data with localStorage, it would be a shopping cart, it's getting now I need to list the data taken on the other page, I can list it through console.log, but I can't call the data, they can help ?
Page Product where, get the items

```
function handleCount(){
    setItemCount(itemCount + parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value));
    
}
function saveCart(template){
    let cartObject = parseCart() // {itemsCount: 1, itemsData: [{'name': pencil, 'quantity': 3, 'price': 2}]};
    cartObject.itemsData.push(template)
    let diversas_cart = {
        'itemsCount': cartObject.itemsData.length,
        'itemsData': cartObject.itemsData
    };
    localStorage.setItem('@diversas/cart', JSON.stringify(diversas_cart))
    return 0;
};

function parseCart(){
    let cartObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('@diversas/cart'));
    console.log(cartObject)
    if(cartObject !== null)
        return cartObject; 
    return {itemsCount: 0, itemsData: []}
};

function addCart(productName, itemCount, price){
    let template = {'name': productName, 'quantity': itemCount, 'price': price};
    //cartItems.push(template);
    saveCart(template);
}

let selectQuantity = []
for (let i = 1; i <= product?.quantity; i++) {
    selectQuantity.push(<option value={i}>{i}</option>)
}

<Link to="/shopCart"><button type="button" className="btn btn-green btn-md btn-block" id="addProduct"
                                        onClick={()=>{handleCount()
                                              addCart(`${product?.productName}`, parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value), `${product?.price}`);
                                        }}
                                    >Buy{" "}</button></Link>
```

Page shopCart

```
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('@diversas/cart'));

var item0Name = cart[0].name;

{cart[0].map(item =>(
      <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-main m-5">
          <main>
                <section> 
                   <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 cardShop" key={item.id}>
                       <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="" />
                       <div class="card-body"></div>
                    </div>
                    <h6>{item.name}</h6>
                 </section>
          </main>
       </div>
     ))}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaxke.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, put the code in the question.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Sorry, I rephrased the question

Comment: `I can list it through console.log` where are you doing that? `I can't call the data` you don't call data, you retrieve it or set it - data is not a function

Comment: @Bravo Don't understand how to give a console.log? and didn't understand the comment? whats wrong? with the functions I created, the items are being taken, so much so that I can give a console.log and see them as in the image I posted.

Comment: `Don't understand how to give a console.log?` you're the one that said you sued console.log

Comment: @Bravo yes I did the console.log, calling my localStorage, and pulled the items that I put in the cart, and now how do I call them?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `parseCart()` method in your code which returns the parsed cart data as an array. You can get the array by simply calling:

```
var cart = parseCart();
```

then you can use the following statements to get the data for each item:

```
var item0Name = cart[0].name;
var item1Name = cart[1].name;
var item0Quantity = cart[0].quantity;
var item1Quantity = cart[1].quantity;
```

**Edit:**

All you need is to use this statement:

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('@diversas/cart'));

var item0Name = cart[0].name;
```

Comment: good afternoon, I tried to perform as informed, but the error that parseCart is not defined. I need to get the data on another page, I don't know if there is a way to define a method from one page to another, if so could you show me? Because what I want is to get the data, I did the console.log in shopCart and it's showing, but it didn't work, I tried to make a map, with shop.map(item=>...) but it didn't work, and something else , needs to be dynamic, this method from what I understand, I would have to call one by one with var item0Name = cart[0].name;
var item0Name = cart[1].name; and so on.

Comment: Actually, all you need is to use a single line from the function parseCart(). Please see the Edit section in my answer.

Comment: This was the error you presented:

Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See in link....

Comment: I did it this way, to see if it's correct, I edited it in my answer above.:

Comment: I added, and updated the code, and it still didn't work, I gave this error:
TypeError: Unable to read property 'map' from undefined

Comment: an observation I gave console.log(cart) and it returned the data just right, it's just a matter of listing even if it's complicated